# Php fwrite not working when content has quotes

Tags: php, quotes, fwrite

Supposing i have this kind of text passing through a form:

Hello my name is Mike, friends call me "SuperMike", hello 'All'!

As you can see , the text contains both type of quotes ( ' " ) and when i try to write a file, it just goes wrong (blank file).

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
    $myfile = fopen("text.html", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, $text);
    fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: It is probably because of the quotes would you try addslashes ( string $str ) http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: but i don't want backslashes to be printed in my file

Comment: you don't have to, just make it this way $text = addslashes($_POST['text']); 
fwrite($myfile, stripslashes($text));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understanding ,below code will help you

```
<form method="post">
    <textarea name="valll"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="ff">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['ff'])) {
    $text = base64_encode($_POST['valll']);
    /*echo $_POST['valll'];
    exit;*/
    $myfile = fopen("text.html", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, base64_decode($text));
    fclose($myfile);
}

?>
```